# Cannot get file of FormData (angular 13) from Symfony 5.4

Tags: file, request, symfony5, angular13, getcontent

I hope you are fine,

I have a problem to get file of FormData in Angular 13 send to Symfony 5.4.

```
onFileSelected1(event:any){
 

       const file:File = event.target.files[0];
        let formData = new FormData();
    
        formData.append("filephotoverif",file);
        for (var [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
          console.log(key, value);
        }
        this.userService.validateUser(formData,this.UserId).subscribe(m => {this.onUploadRefresh();});
      }


  public validateUser(data: any, id:number):  Observable<User[]>
  {
    return this.server.postbis<any>('personne/imageverif/'+id, data).pipe(
      map(res => res),
      catchError(err =>
        {

          return [];
        })
    );
  }

public postbis<T>(url: string, body: T, secure:boolean=true): Observable<any>
{
  if(secure){
    let token=sessionStorage.getItem('id_token');
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
if (typeof token === 'string'){
   headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data').set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token ).set( 'method' , 'POST');
  }
  return this.call(() =>this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + url, body,  {'headers':headers}));
 }
 else{
  return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + url, body);
 }
}
```

I have the resource|string with a `$request->getContent()`,so before that was working to get a file with `$fileversocarteid=$req->files->get('fileversocarteid');`.but not now, it give me a `null`. And the dump of my Request donot reveale any files, query or request.

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request {#51 ▼
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#93 ▶}
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#99 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
  +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#94 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
  +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#90 ▼
    #parameters: array:113 [▶]
  }
  +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#91 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
  +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#92 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#89 ▼
    #headers: array:20 [▶]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/api/personne/imageverif/5"
  #requestUri: "/api/personne/imageverif/5"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: "json"
  #session: Closure() {#202 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -preferredFormat: null
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  -isSafeContentPreferred: null
  basePath: ""
}
```

That's my console.log of my FormData (Angular 13)

```
filephotoverif 
File {name: 'IMG-20211220-WA0001.jpg', lastModified: 1640009345334, lastModifiedDate: Mon Dec 20 2021 15:09:05 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 177618, …}
lastModified: 1640009345334
lastModifiedDate: Mon Dec 20 2021 15:09:05 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) {}
name: "IMG-20211220-WA0001.jpg"
size: 177618
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
```

And that's my resource|string with `dump($req->getContent())`

```
b"------WebKitFormBoundaryEXJJL0VPLSS5ODRtContent-Disposition: form-data; name="filephotoverif"; filename="IMG-20211220-WA0001.jpg"Content-Type: image/jpeg Ï Ó\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00 ß\x00"Exif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x01\x01\x12\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 █\x00C\x00\x02\x01\x01\x02\x01\x01\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x03\x05\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x0...etc
```

I have use php 8.1.1, 8.0.14 and now 7.4.27 same bug.

Maybe it's the bcrypt module that I have add to angular, that said that provock some bug, I don't know.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I come back to you, so I did a lot of stuff so I don't know what solved the problem, while knowing that the last thing I changed was, to delete the `set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')` and I also put symfony on https server. In addition to all the version changes of php and symfony. If anyone knows what solved the problem, I'd love to listen.

Answer (score 0):

In fact for me, it started to works when I added the Content-type multipart/formdata (I had a JWT interceptor that was setting up my content-type as application/json).

If it can helps in any way...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).